# Can a for loop be used to create an 'else if' statement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
if(case) {
  //statement
} else if {
 //statement
}

for() {
 //loop to create more else if statements
}

else {
}
```

Just curious to know if this should/can be done.

Example usage: If the user is making a selection from a dropdown list with values from 1-50, and there are different conditions to be executed onchange for each of those 50 values; else-if statements are then dynamically created using the for-loop for all those 50 different conditions.

===============================================================

Edit:

Great, thanks everyone. You just helped me save a great deal of time that I otherwise would've wasted trying to get this to work somehow; until eventually realizing it can't be done.

The only reason I tried something like this was because I didn't want to write 50+ else-if statements for each of my dropdown option.

Thank you Jonas W, Shane_IL for your answers.

Comment: i think u cannot use, usually ``if else`` will appear inside ``for`` loop

Comment: for ... else is not valid

Comment: That will throw a syntax error.

Comment: Answer is _You can't_

Comment: There will be better ways of doing things. what is your case scenario of thinking such a bold one?

Comment: Can you give little sample data? Its not straight but there can be ways to validate

Comment: please add some examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May have a look at **switches**:

```
switch(input.value){
 case 1:
    alert("value is one");
 break;
 case 2:
   alert("value is two");
 break;
}
```

Or **recursive functions**:

```
function validate(val,start=0){
 if(val==start){
  alert("val is "+start);
 }else{
  validate(val,start+1);
 }
 }

validate(27);//will go trough 26 elses and one if...
```

Or create an **array to resolve**:

```
var resolve=[" one","two","three"];
alert(resolve[input.value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no syntax that can do that.

You can create a unique evaluation function for each value, then you can do something like this:

```
for(let i=0;i < values.length; i++){
  if(values[i].evaluatorFunc()){
    //doSomething
  }
  else{
    doSomethingElse()  
  }
}

function doSomethingElse(){
  //here you can run the same code anytime the loop enters else
}
```

Comment: If values is an array i<values is a bit weird

Comment: Doh! .length, i always forget .length